# Ruby Rails ошибка при попытке удаления записи

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Есть проект, подключил Devise, настроил авторизацию. Создал модель `Task`, подвязал вьюху на создание + ссылки просмотр, редактирование, удаление.

При переходе по ссылке которая должна **удалять `Task`** происходит ошибка, конкретно - загружается следующий URL: `http://localhost:3000/tasks.1`

Ошибка:

> No route matches [DELETE] "/tasks.1"

**Пути:** http://joxi.ru/DmBNGWwSN66W7m

**Экшен контроллера для удаления:**

```
def destroy
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])
    @task.destroy

    redirect_to tasks_path
  end
```

**View:**

```
<div class="container" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
  <h1>TASK#PAGE</h1>

  <%= form_for(@task, remote: true) do |f| %>
      <%= f.label :name %><br>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>
      <%= f.submit %>
  <% end %>

  <br>

  <table id="tasks" class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
      <th colspan="4">Задача</th>
    </tr>
    <% @tasks.each do |task| %>
        <tr>
          <%= render @tasks %>

          <td><%= link_to 'Показать', task_path(task), class: 'btn btn-success' %></td>
          <td><%= link_to 'Редактировать', edit_task_path(task), class: 'btn btn-success' %></td>
          <td><%= link_to 'Удалить', tasks_path(task), class: 'btn btn-success', class: 'btn btn-success',
                          method: :delete,
                          data: {confirm: 'Вы уверены?'} %></td>
        </tr>
    <% end %>
  </table>

</div>
```

**В `routes.rb`:**

```
    Rails.application.routes.draw do

  get 'home/index'

  get 'devise' => 'sessions#new'

  devise_for :users

  resources :profiles
  resources :projects
  resources :tasks

  root 'home#index'

end
```

Comment: Маршруты прикрепите?

Comment: home_index_path GET /home/index(.:format) home#index

Comment: Да уже неважно %)

Comment: Думал оживить если еще не поздно этот вопрос так как проблема сново актуальна - в прошлый раз как то само собой решилось, а сейчас в новом проекте - все то же самое(

Comment: Тогда хотя бы к вопросу их приложите.

Comment: Приложил скрин всех путей

Comment: ...и вопрос актуализируйте, нажали явно на другое.

Comment: Вопрос отредактировал, внес всю информацию. Как актуализировать сам вопрос к сожалению не знаю(

Comment: Под "актуализировать" это и понималось. Добавьте `routes.rb`, а я пока гляну на предмет переоткрытия.

Comment: Файл routes.rb добавил

Answer (score 1):

Решение проблемы - View в ссылке на редактирование необходимо заменить строку на следующую:

```
<td><%= link_to 'Удалить', task_path(task), remote: true, class: 'btn btn-success', class: 'btn btn-success',
                          method: :delete,
                          data: {confirm: 'Вы уверены?'} %></td>
```

После удаление стало работать корректно.

Comment: Чтобы дополнить свой вопрос, просим Вас воспользоваться опцией редактирования. Кнопку «Опубликовать ответ» следует использовать только для исчерпывающих ответов на вопросы. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/55992)

Comment: @alexanderbarakin это не дополнение. Это ответ. Хотя в диффе, прямо скажем, много лишнего.